# my monitor shows Win8 is loading, but then turns black

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, laptop, display

I have a Dell monitor: Dell U2312HM

it's connected to my PC (AVG) and to my MacBook (Display port)

I have set the mac to be the only display for this monitor.

And when I was done with the laptop, I plugged the display port out and turned off the laptop.

The thing is that now my monitor shows Win8 is loading, but then turns black and after 10 seconds goes to sleep mode.

I have started win8 in safe mode and deleted the monitor driver, just in case it saves some state there. Did a restart, but it didn't help.

Tried to change the monitor input, playing with the buttons on it - but it didn't help 
(as the loading of Win8 is shown anyhow).

My monitor works, because it shows

1) windows is loading

2) the laptop screen when it's plugged in

- plugging another monitor to my PC works just fine. anything is shown

So i suspect it's settings issue.

How can I fix this?

i entered a safe-mode and deleted the monitor's driver, but after a restart it didn't help

[image]

Comment: What PC is it you are hooking up to? And, You can see everything if you boot into safe mode?

Comment: yes, I see everything when on safe mode. I have a 10 months old PC with win8. Intel CPU.

Comment: I have a similar issue did you solve it?

Comment: dont remember. sorry